# Why Binance Testnet transaction fails?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, binance, contract

I don't know why this transaction fails:

https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xe464a4bb94268c97c0e5f795f6fb336d982c1570c426e8518266875515d42a76

It's called like this:

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
const value = web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether');  // Define how much ether you want to send.
const fromAddress = accounts[0];
// Create a transaction object
const tx = {
  from: fromAddress,
  value: value, // This sends 0.1 Ether along with the transaction
  gas: 3000000, // Adjust the gas limit as needed
};

contract.methods.addPlayer('PAID').send(tx)
// first we receive the transaction hash
.on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
  console.log("hash received");
  console.log(hash);
})
```

If I make this call directly from online Remix, it works flawlessly.
Like here:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xd8d3004ad3b63e6ffaff50323086af24fa30a52f01777eb6290356f12ee8373f

I noticed there is a difference in input data in the details of the transaction.
Yet contract method is called correctly.

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Jure

Comment: The failing transaction has empty `data` field, while the successful transaction `data` field signalizes executing the `addPlayer()` function with the "PAID" parameter... It seems like your JS snippet overrides the `data` field into an empty value, not sure why though.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. Can't see why, because this already worked. and the code is standard:
// Create a transaction object
    const tx = {
      from: fromAddress,
      value: valueWei, // This sends 0.1 Ether along with the transaction
      gas: 3000000, // Adjust the gas limit as needed
    };

    contract.methods.addPlayer('PAID').send(tx)
    // first we receive the transaction hash
    .on('transactionHash', (hash) => {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny enough.
The code was allright.

I downgraded web3 version from 4.1.1 to 4.0.3 and it started working.
Thanks to you all!